# Why `TRegEx.split` returned a empty string as first element?

Tags: regex, delphi

Why `TRegEx.split` returned a empty string as first element?

- My string: `{name}text`.
- My RegExp: `TRegEx.split('{name}text', '\{(.*)\}');`

And my result:

```
[empty]
name
text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is an empty zero-length match in front of the delimiter, that will be added to the result. That is similar to most regex implementation I know. Sadly the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Split) doesn't note this.

Note that your pattern will overlap if there are multiple `{...}` string due to `.*` being greedy - rather use `\{(.*?)\}` or `\{[^{}]*\}`. Compare the results on a string like `a{b}c{d}e`:

```
var
  S: string;
begin
  for S in TRegex.Split('a{b}c{d}e', '\{(.*)\}') do
  begin
    WriteLn(S);   //->['a','b{c}d','e']
  end;
  WriteLn('-------------------');
  for S in TRegex.Split('a{b}c{d}e', '\{(.*?)\}') do
  begin
    WriteLn(S);  //-> ['a','b','c','d','e']
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Final code without an empty elements:

```
for buf in TRegEx.split(str, '\{(.*?)\}') do
  if (buf <> '') then matches := matches + [buf];
```